# Are there any RF remote control circuits without any ICs?

Tags: wireless, frequency, radio, remote-control

I'm currently trying to make a simple 3 channels RF remote control circuit but without any ICs or micro-controller. I'm Googling but it seems to not populate (useful results). Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Do transistors count as ICs?

Comment: The line for when you count certain components as ICs is a bit hazy. Not including such seems like an exercise in futility, It can be done reasonably with just OP-amps, but are they ICs?

Comment: What sort of information do you want to transmit on the three channels?

Comment: @ThePhoton: No, ICs I mean the thing like blackbox :D, I want to build an curruit from R, L, C, Trans, Wire, and any things we can easy make ourself

Comment: @DaveTweed: I want control 3 lights from my RC panel

Comment: You'll need transistors or valves to build a transmitter, and in practice a crystal as well. You could build effectively an audio transmitter-reciever pair, then encode the channels as tones or audio bands within that. It will, of course, be much larger and more expensive than the IC implementation.

Comment: @BìnhNguyên It can be done using basic electronic components. However, you need to provide more details on what you need/require. Based on your comments, we understand that you only need to switch ON/OFF three lights/lamps. An important question: How far will the remote be at maximum?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên Not related to your question but on how to use this site: Always wait for at least 24 hours or a number of answers before accepting one. You will not be encouraging people to give more answers (some new answers may be better). As a guide, try to settle out first all pending inquiries in the comments before accepting an answer.

Comment: @shimofuri: I'm sorry, I'll put this down to experience for the next time :-(

Answer (score 6):

Here's a couple of [transmitter circuits](http://www.modelenginenews.org/cardfile/images/tx_mk234.jpg) from [this page](http://www.modelenginenews.org/cardfile/ed_radios.html) and a few [receivers.](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/norcimradiocontrol/Radio17.htm) To be historically accurate, the receiver would drive a relay with three tuned reeds to activate three channels, according to the frequencies modulating the transmitter...

Enjoy!

Comment: +1  You gave the OP a perfectly valid answer given the rather laughable design constraints, and he accepted the answer!  This probably says more about human nature than electrical engineering, but it is still worth the +1.

Comment: To be honest I was hoping someone would chip in with slightly newer references! (@Binh : feel free to un-accept the answer!) Though as it happens, it's not so silly an idea; triode valve circuits adapt quite well to JFets (and tetrode to JFET cascodes), and these have a quite amazing simplicity about them. (though transmitters nowadays really OUGHT to be crystal controlled...) Replacing the tuned reeds with opamp-based bandpass filters might be quite a reasonable concession to modernity...

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Thanks, but if possible, you can edit your answer :D

Again: Sorry for my bad english :-(

Answer (score 2):

An author named Paul Newell wrote a couple of books both called Theory and Practise of Model Radio Control, the first edition described building a four or five channel AM 27MHz proportional RC set, no ICs all transistor, they used to allow 100kHz adjacent channels with that spec.  He rewrote it to describe another set with more channels, FM (FSK), narrower (maybe 10kHz offset?) channel spacing, that version used ICs from memory.  The first book dates to the early '70s, the later maybe early '80s.